# accessing the private memeber variable of super class in the child class through reflection

Tags: java

I have this class that is RMIserviceexporter basically this class is spring remoting now in this there is a int variable named registry port

```
private int registryPort = Registry.REGISTRY_PORT; // which is set to 1099
```

and it has setter methods

```
public void setRegistryPort(int registryPort) {
    this.registryPort = registryPort;
}
```

now I have extended this class in later stages that is have i have created a new  class abcexpoerter which basically extend RMIserviceexporter , I have to access this registryPort variable of RMIserviceexporter that is the variable name registryPort  but i can not access this variable since there is no getter method defined in the parent class now please advise me can i access this private variable value in the extended lass through reflection

```
   class abcexpoter extends RMIServiceExporter
        {
            // now in this class i want to access the registerPort variable value  please advise how can i //access this registry port variable inside this class
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You *can*, but you *shouldn't*. The member is presumably private *for a reason*.

This is covered in the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and [`java.lang.reflect` package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) documentation: You get the field via [`getDeclaredField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-), then force it accessible using [`setAccessible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-boolean-), then use the relevant `getXyz` method from [`Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) (`getInt`, `getString`, whatever) to get its value.

For instance, since it's an `int`:

```
Field field = TheClass.class.getDeclaredField("registryPort");
field.setAccessible(true);
int port = field.getInt(this);
```